# Golang Организация Struct-a для модератора и администратора

Tags: golang

Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно создавать Struct для каждой формы разный, например:

```
type Film struct {
    ID int
    Title string `form:"title" validate:"min:10"`
    // и еще 20 полей
}

f := Film{}
c.Validate(&f) // сохраняем данные из формы и проверяем
```

Администратору можно редактировать все поля, и поэтому для получения формы использую этот структ, для модератора можно все кроме изменения Title и поэтому нужно создать новый структ с такими же полями только без поля Title. Просто если не создавать новый структ то, скажем curl-ом, можно отослать запрос включая title и он сохранится. Просто разница в использовании 1-3 поля (из 20-30 полей), а нужно создавать отдельный структ? Или вы пишите как-то по другому?

Answer (score 0):

```
type BaseStruct struct {
   ID     int
   Rating int
}

type Movie struct {
   *BaseStruct
   Title string `form:"title" validate:"min:10"`
}

type Film struct {
   *BaseStruct
}
```

Попробуйте так, чтоб не дублировать код, это что-то вроде наследования структур

Comment: Я в курсе о такой возможности в GO (встраивание структур), но меня это тоже не устраивает, слишком много стуктов плодится, потом голова боли что и где, и куда. Короче, подумав, для себя сделал вывод, что нужно писать по другому.

Comment: Вы обязательно напишите как нужно писать, в ответе на свой вопрос. Может кому-то пригодится)